Helping hand with PowerShell and tables
I need some advice if you would be so kind.
I have this portion of PowerShell code with some variables:

$Tabla = @{
'01-Name' = $cambiumEffectiveDeviceName.Data
'02-Uptime (DD:HH:MM:SS)' = $cambiumSystemUptime.Data
'03-RSSI (dBm)' = $cambiumSTADLRSSI.Data
'04-SNR (dB)' = $cambiumSTADLSNR.Data
'05-TX Power (dBm)' = $cambiumSTAConductedTXPower.Data
'06-MCS Downlink' = $cambiumSTADownlinkMCSMode.Data
'07-MCS Uplink' = $cambiumSTAUplinkMCSMode.Data
'08-TX Capacity (%)' = $staTxCapacity.Data
'09-TX Quality (%)' = $staTxQuality.Data
'10-ARP Table (MAC, IP, IF)' = $arp_table.Data
'11-Port Forwarding (PORT)' = $portfwdtable.Data
}

# Display table

$Tabla | Sort-Object -Property Name | Format-Table

I need to display the table output in four columns (Num, Name, Data, Units) and sorted by the Num column.
The final result should be like this:
Num   Name          Data (from the variable)          Units
01    Name          $cambiumEffectiveDeviceName.Data  Name
02    Uptime        $cambiumSystemUptime.Data         DD:HH:MM:SS
03    RSSI          $cambiumSTADLRSSI.Data            dBm
04    SNR           $cambiumSTADLSNR.Data             dB
05    TX Power      $cambiumSTAConductedTXPower.Data  dBm
06    MCS Downlink  $cambiumSTADownlinkMCSMode.Data   Mode
07    MCS Uplink    $cambiumSTAUplinkMCSMode.Data     Mode
08    TX Capacity   $staTxCapacity.Data               %
09    TX Quality    $staTxQuality.Data                %
10    ARP Table     $arp_table.Data                   MAC,IP,IF
11    Port Forward  $portfwdtable.Data                Port

`
The Column Data must show the result of the variable not the name...
I tried this approach with no luck:
# Crear tabla
$Tabla = @(
    @{Num='01';Name='Name';Data=$cambiumEffectiveDeviceName.Data;Units='Name' }
    @{Num='02';Name='Uptime';Data=$cambiumSystemUptime.Data;Units='DD:HH:MM:SS' }
    @{Num='03';Name='RSSI';Data=$cambiumSTADLRSSI.Data;Units='dBm' }
    @{Num='04';Name='SNR';Data=$cambiumSTADLSNR.Data;Units='dB' }
    @{Num='05';Name='TX Power';Data=$cambiumSTAConductedTXPower.Data;Units='dBm' }
    @{Num='06';Name='MCS Downlink';Data=$cambiumSTADownlinkMCSMode.Data;Units='Mode' }
    @{Num='07';Name='MCS Uplink';Data=$cambiumSTAUplinkMCSMode.Data;Units='Mode' }
    @{Num='08';Name='TX Capacity';Data=$staTxCapacity.Data;Units='%' }
    @{Num='09';Name='TX Quality';Data=$staTxQuality.Data;Units='%' }
    @{Num='10';Name='ARP Table';Data=$arp_table.Data;Units='MAC,IP,IF' }
    @{Num='11';Name='Port Forward';Data=$portfwdtable.Data;Units='Port' }
)
# Mostrar tabla
$Tabla | Sort-Object -Property Num | Format-Table -Property Num, Name, Data, Units

Result:

Num Name  Data Units
--- ----  ---- -----
    Units
    Num
    Data
    Name
    Units
    Num
    Data
    Name
    Units
    Num
    Data
    Name
    Units
    Num
    Data
    Name
    Units
    Num
    Data
    Name
    Units
    Num
    Data
    Name
    Units
    Num
    Data
    Name
    Units
    Num
    Data
    Name
    Units

How could I achieve this? Any advice?
Thanks!

simply prepend [pscustomobject] before each @ symbol in you $Tabla: [pscustomobject]@{Num='01';Name='Name.... this way you will end up with an array of custom objects instead of an array of hashtables and will have no issues displaying it in your console

In your example, $Tabla is an array of hashtables (collections of key / value pairs) and what you're expecting as output is a collection of custom objects (PSCustomObject). For this, the solution to your problem is as simple as prepending the [pscustomobject] type accelerator before the definition of each hashtable:
$Tabla = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{Num = '01'; Name = 'Name'; Data = $cambiumEffectiveDeviceName.Data; Units = 'Name' }
    [pscustomobject]@{Num = '02'; Name = 'Uptime'; Data = $cambiumSystemUptime.Data; Units = 'DD:HH:MM:SS' }
    [pscustomobject]@{Num = '03'; Name = 'RSSI'; Data = $cambiumSTADLRSSI.Data; Units = 'dBm' }
    # and so on here...
)
$Tabla | Sort-Object -Property Num | Format-Table -Property Num, Name, Data, Units

Another alternative that would work in PowerShell 6+ is to use Select-Object instead of Format-Table, this cmdlet knows how to convert input hashtables to PSCustomObject:
$Tabla = @(
    @{Num = '01'; Name = 'Name'; Data = $cambiumEffectiveDeviceName.Data; Units = 'Name' }
    @{Num = '02'; Name = 'Uptime'; Data = $cambiumSystemUptime.Data; Units = 'DD:HH:MM:SS' }
    @{Num = '03'; Name = 'RSSI'; Data = $cambiumSTADLRSSI.Data; Units = 'dBm' }
    # and so on here...
)
$Tabla | Select-Object Num, Name, Data, Units | Sort-Object -Property Num

